# Meilisearch faceted search attribute

Tags: meilisearch

I have a data set as below

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ThinkPad T14",
      "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lenovo"
      },
      "price": 599
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "ThinkPad X1",
      "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lenovo"
      },
      "price": 799
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Yoga L7",
      "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lenovo"
      },
      "price": 499
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Vostro",
      "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Dell"
      },
      "price": 499
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Latitude",
      "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Dell"
      },
      "price": 899
    }
```

I want to get facetd result as below

```
Category:
Lenovo (3)
Dell   (2)
```

How can I do that? I want to do faceted filter by `category.id`.

```
    "facetDistribution": {
        "category": {},
        "category.id": {
            "1": 3,
            "2": 2
        },
        "category.name": {
            "Dell": 2,
            "Lenovo": 3
        }
    },
    "facetStats": {
        "category.id": {
            "min": 1.0,
            "max": 2.0
        }
    }
```